# How to create a regex that matches either 0 occurrences, or between 7 and 50 occurrences?

Tags: regex, quantifiers

In regex, I can match zero or more occurrences with `*`, and between 7 and 50 occurrences with `{7,50}`. How can I match *either* zero *or* between 7 and 50 occurrences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the range match and make it optional with `?` (match 0 or 1 instance).

Python, since a language wasn't specified:

```
>>> import re
>>> test = 'abaxbaxxxxxxbaxxxxxxxbaxxxxxxxxb'
>>> re.findall('a(?:x{7,50})?b',test)
['ab', 'axxxxxxxb', 'axxxxxxxxb']
```

- Match `a`.
- `(?:n)` match `n` but don't make a capture group.grouping.
- `(?:x{7,50})` groups match 7-50 occurrences of `x`.
- `(?:x{7,50})?` makes it optional (0 or 1 occurrence)
- Match `b`

Without the non-capturing group you'd get:

```
>>> re.findall('a(x{7,50})?b',test)
['', 'xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxx']
```

See a working example @ https://regex101.com/r/qkziuu/1

Answer (score 0):

you can use this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/SloXtH/1)

```
(\S{7,50})?
```

`\S{7,50}` means 7 to 50 occurrence of non-whitespace character

`(\S{7,50})?` means 0 or 1 occurrence of `\S{7,50}`